# Upload image evenly into a directory structure

Tags: php

Im sure this question has been asked thousand of times, so here goes my version...

I have a form that uploads images...
Every image contains an unique id. I use the following function to generate my unid id:

```
function generateUnid($key) {   
    $name = $_FILES[$key]['name']; //get image name from global variable $_FILES
    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //get image extension
    $prefix = 'fc'; //prefix for unid

    do {
       $unid = uniqid($prefix, true); //generate a unid
       $filename = $unid . '.' . $ext; //replace image name with unid
       $path = PATH_UPLOAD_ARTWORK . $filename; // image path
    } while (file_exists($path)); // check if the image name exists

    return $filename;
}
```

A sample of return values is:

```
fc4e7801523a04e6.06876802.jpg
```

So far so good. Now, i want to create some sort of directory structure for my images. Something similar like:

```
0
   0
   1
   2
      fc4e7801523a04e6.06876802.jpg
      ...
   3
   ...
1
  0
  1
  2
  3
  ...
2
  0
  1
  ...
```

I could probably get the last 2 integers in my unique id for filing the image in the correct directory. But, i'm not to sure if that is the correct strategy...
How can i make sure that the images are filed evenly in the folders. I don't want to find my self with one folder that contains 12 000 images and one folder with 1 500 images...

Am i doing it the correct way by extracting the last 2 numbers of my uniq? Are there better ways for filing the image evenly?

Thanks

Comment: I do wonder why you want to put the files into arbitrary buckets like this? Is it because you anticipate a very large number of files and want to avoid OS performance issues that sometimes arise when many files are stored in the same directory? Why not store according to date, or username, or something like that?

Comment: exactly! i do like to anticipate and plan in advance. I´ve seen this method use in a lot of cases. I like the fact that i could have a very large nunber of pictures and not run into perfomance issues later on. I´m the only one uploading images, and i could upload a bunch one day and nothing for days or months... So i can´t use name o date...

Comment: So ... you think that you could potentially upload more files in one day than could be comfortably handled by your OSs filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the unique id is uniformly (psuedo)random, which I think it is, this strategy will work pretty well I think. There will inevitably be a few folders with many more or many less than the average, predicted by [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

A slightly better technique for "binning" the images is to use the modulo (%) of many digits from the uid, rather than using the last two digits, in case the digits you have picked have some kind of pattern.

My advice would be to give it a go and see how it works for you. Ideally, you could create a "test harness" which calls the algorithm hundreds of thousands of times, after which you could assess whether the distribution of files in the directory structure is appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: I´ve use your advice and did some tests. Surprisingly, it did fine! I´ve uploaded 150 000 files and all files ended up binning evenly in the folders

Comment: Cool! And the folder with the maximum number of files isn't too many for your liking? Importantly, you can never be 100% certain that a folder won't end up getting 300 billion files in it. (You can only be 99.999999999999999% certain.)

While you're counting the number of files in each folder, you might as well plot the data on a histogram! Count the number of folders that have X files and plot it (with X for the x-axis, the count for y-axis). You should get a reasonably pretty bell graph centered on 1500 (if there are 100 folders for 150k files).